# Insert SQLite3 with selfcheck in itself

Tags: sqlite, insert

i have a table called scanHistory that holds scanID and HostID as foreign key which are actually primary key to their respective tables. I want to write an insert query in SQLite to avoid inserting same values of scanID to its respective HostID meaning No two same hosts can have same scanID something Like:

```
ScanID - 100 HostID - 1
ScanID - 100 HostID - 2
ScanID - 200 HostID - 1
```

I tried this query

```
INSERT INTO scanHistory (NULL,4000,1) Select 1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from scanHistory);
```

But it's giving me error stating

```
Error: near "NULL": Syntax Error
```

what i am doing wrong? The table looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE scanHistory(
ScanHistoryID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
HostID INTEGER REFERENCES host(HostID),
ScanID INTEGER REFERENCES scan(ScanID));
```

Comment: it's interpreting that group as column names, for which NULL is invalid.   You probably want a `values` keyword in there.

Comment: @evilotto If i add VALUES its giving me a syntax error near SELECT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just letting the database enforce it?

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_scan_host ON ScanHistory(ScanID, HostID);
```

Now you can no longer insert duplicate HostID/ScanID pairs.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/fa2ca/13).

If you just mean that `ScanID` needs to be unique, you can create the unique index just on that, and the database will enforce that no two rows with the same `ScanID` can be inserted;

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_scan_host ON ScanHistory(ScanID);
```

If you want an error back when you try to insert a value, just use `INSERT INTO...` as usual. If you want to ignore the error, use `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO...`.

EDIT: To do it using SQL only, you can use;

```
INSERT INTO ScanHistory (ScanID, HostID) SELECT 100, 1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM ScanHistory WHERE ScanID=100 AND HostID=1
);
```

Comment: I am trying to work on the combination in this way because i'm testing this query but will actually be used logically in my python script

Comment: @NottyShinchan Are you saying that you can't add an index to the database? The query is no different as long as the index is there.

Comment: Whats the actual usage of unique index? If i use it i will have unique hosts with unique scans? because my concern is host and scan have many to many relationship among them so 1 host can be among many scans and 1 scan be among many hosts but no two same hosts should have same scans

Comment: @NottyShinchan That's exactly what the first index does, keeps any scan/host pair unique. You can insert (1,1)(1,2),(2,1),(2,2) but not (1,1)(1,1).

Comment: Great..then Do i have to maintain the results of that unique index because i have to ultimately use it in my script?

Comment: @NottyShinchan The index, when placed there, will update itself when the table changes, no need to manually keep it up to date in any way. The only thing you may want to think about in your Python script is whether you want an error back when you try to insert duplicates or not. See the updated answer on that.

Comment: Thanks...that query was the only thing i needed. You are great!